# How to get a diff between 2 objects as a mongodb update query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have object a and object b:

```
var a = {x: 1};
var b = {x: 5};
```

And I would like to get this:

```
var update = getDiffUpdate(a, b);
// update should be {$inc: {x: 4}}
```

Do you have any idea on how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a basic JavaScript problem:

```
var inc = Math.abs( a.x - b.x );
db.collection.update(query,{ "$inc": { "x": inc }});
```

Or something along those lines. You can traverse the object and construct if neeeded

Comment: lol I know how to do that. But you have to take in account more complex objects and functions. For example your solution doesn't work for simple nested objects. I already have build some part of it, but I wonder if there is anything already built?

Comment: You left the behavior completely unspecified beyond the obvious case and Neil gave you the simplest answer...what exactly were you expecting? What is a simple nested object for which Neil's solution doesn't work, how should the correct function behave on the input, and how are you making your choice about how you would traverse and determine differences in the general case?

Comment: @wdberkeley For at least the forth time now. "Tag" the user you are talking to in your comments or they will not see it. "Tagging" includes the username prefixed with `@` as I have done here. Otherwise you are just talking to the author,and what is the point of that?